# Strange thing about using hibernate session's saveOrUpdate method

Tags: mysql, database, hibernate

I am using hibernate to connect to a mysql database.

My saveOrUpdate method is :

```
public void saveOrUpdate(T t){
    Session session = HibernateUtil.getSession();
    Transaction transaction = session.beginTransaction();
    session.saveOrUpdate(t);
    transaction.commit();
}
```

I used this method actually for about half year, it worked well.
But now when I do junit test using this method, it seems suck.
I do saveOrUpdate first and then use Criteria to query, it gets the result seems to be right, but in database nothing actually changed.

Could anyone please give me any hint about what's happening here?

Thank you very much.

Answer (score 1):

What is your JUnit configuration set to for transactions? I believe it is set to rollback all the transactions in the test. It should rightly be so, as after a test the database should be put back into a consistent/known state. The correctness of your code should rely on how you write the test and not the records being physically present in the database.

Comment: Thank you for the answer, I didn't know i have to change setting specifically for junit. May I also ask why when I use hql, it then works well?

Comment: @XuanziHan Do you mean why it works when you run this method in your application?

Comment: yes, and now in the junit, it seems sometimes work,sometimes stuck. Thank you

Comment: @XuanziHan It will work in your application because the application is meant to commit to the database based on the success or failure of the transaction. But Junit runs in a sort of sandboxed environment which should ideally rollback all the transactions once the test case has finished. Refer to this [link]http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.0.5.RELEASE/reference/testing.html#testing-tx[/link] and pay attention to `@TransactionConfiguration`